# Does JavaScript convert Array into an Object internally?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am aware that everything is an object in JavaScript but something struck me when i was using the console of Internet Explorer -F12 (Yes IE, not allowed to use other browsers)

If i type a sample array in the console as:

```
[1,2]
```

the output is

```
1,2{
    0:1,
    1:2
   }
```

Does this mean that JavaScript converts Array into an Object with keys and values?

Comment: Array's are object, so yes or no depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Is this really exactly the output you're getting? It doesn't even make any sense

Comment: the output shown is merely a visualization by a graphical debug console... you can log JSON.stringify(arr) if in doubt...

Comment: @dandavis The third comma was bothering me.

Comment: `typeof [1,2,3]` results in `"object"` so there is no primitive object type

Answer (score 3):

Yes, arrays in JS are simply objects with numeric keys.  You could do the reverse:

```
var myarray = { 0: 'first', 1: 'second', 2: 'third' };
console.log(myarray[1]);
```

Comment: for some reason that "array"s length property is wrong and [].join doesn't work either... Maybe it's not-so-simple?

Comment: Well, Array is a special object so my example does not inherit the Array.prototype.  So I guess in that sense it's not the exact same thing.  But the OP was asking if the data itself is stored the same way.

Comment: if the question is is " the data itself is stored the same way", the answer is still no. V8 for example would store the OP's code as an intArray, but an object "equivalent" uses a different data structure altogether.